# Not fire click event in Select2 container

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am developing front-end using Bootstrap select2 library.

Select2 is like image:

[image: select2 image]

When I click email link , it does not fire click event , then only select2 dropdown is opened.

How can I fire click event in select2 container?

Comment: This is probably going to need some more detail - I can't make much sense of this. Do you have some code you can show?

Comment: I used only select2.min.js file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).